# Only make the block move in the border/ child and parent animate

Tags: jquery

How can I make it that the block can only move in the parent?

Now it can move out of the parent, which is the #border.

Ty for your help.

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $(document).on('keydown', function(e)
    {
        switch(e.which)
        {
            //Linkse toets
            case 37: $('#blokje').animate(
            {
                left: '-=100px'
            },1000);
            break;


            //Rechtse toets
            case 39: $('#blokje').animate(
            {
                left: '+=100px'
            },1000);
            break;

            //Onder toets
            case 40: $('#blokje').animate(
            {
                top: '+=100px'
            },1000);
            break;

            //Boven toets
            case 38: $('#blokje').animate(
            {
                top: '-=100px'
            },1000);
            break;
        }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Blokje</title>
            <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <script src="_js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
            <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Gebruik de pijltoetsen om het kader te verplaatsen</h2>
        <div id="border">
            <div id="blokje"></div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#blokje 
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;

    position: relative;
    background-color: #FFFF99;
}

#border {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 600px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of jQuery's [`position()`](https://api.jquery.com/position/) method.

Firstly, change your css rule for `#border` to include `position: relative;` This will allow you to get the position of child elements *relative* to the parent.

Now in your jQuery, you need to store the current position of your block:

```
var blockPos = $('#blokje').position();//returns an object with the top and left positions
```

Now all that is needed is to check whether the block is inside the border:

```
//check top - when the block is going up
if(blockPos.top > 0){
  //animate block
}

//check left - when the block is going left
if(blockPos.left > 0){
  //animate block
}

//check bottom - when the block is going down
if((blockPos.top + $('#blokje').height()) < $('#border').height()){
  //animate block
}

//check right - when the block is going right
if((blockPos.left + $('#blokje').width()) < $('#border').width()){
  //animate block
}
```

[working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/imclarky/te5Lksfu/)

---

**Just an extra note:**
As you are using `keydown` as the event the block position is taken at the moment the key is pressed; therefore meaning, if the block was inside the border at the time of pressing the key, it will continue to animate even if it crosses the border.

Therefore, it may be better to use `keyup` instead. However this limits you to one movement per keystroke, and I'm not sure if that's what you want.